# Automount using AutoFS and AFP permission issue

Tags: macos, permissions, mount, afp, autofs

I have a FreeNAS server of which I'd like to mount volumes on my Mac. 
I'm using afp and mounting via Autofs following [this tutorial](https://blog.netnerds.net/2013/10/mounting-nas-volumes-in-mac-os-x-the-right-way/). The folder / mountpoints on which I mount the drives are located in ~ (in my case ~/Data).

After setting up and using automount -vc, everything runs fine. When I reboot and try to access the drives again, I get permission errors. These problems are usually solved my using umount ~/Data (the volume) (which, I guess, unmounts and then automounts it correctly and therefore somehow solving the permission issue). This is kind of a annoying workaround, hence I'm looking for a solution.

The mountpoint on my Mac has these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 Frank  staff         68 Aug  1 15:26 Data
```

The mounted folder on my Mac has these permissions:

```
drwx------@   1 Frank  staff        264 Jan 10 14:33 Data
```

The volume in FreeNAS is owned by the same user as I'm logged in on my Mac.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue. But finally now solution yet.
If you look with command sudo mount, then you will see in case of failure the the mount point was not mounted by any user. 
In case of working your user will have mounted it